# How to select the database to run an .sql file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

If I have multiple database connections set up in IntelliJ IDEA. How can I select the database connection that I want to run my `.sql` files in?

In my case, I have two different PostgreSQL DB connections set up (local and remote) and I can open a terminal to each. But when I select a `something.sql` file and run it, it picks one connection automatically (even if it's closed) and I'm unable to figure out how to tell IDEA to use the other one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found it, after I went through many menus and settings.
The database (or databases) can be selected in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Interestingly, it's available only sometimes; in other files, a pop-up dialog shows each time.

For details, see [Running SQL Script Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/running-sql-script-files.html) in IntelliJ help.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
psql mydatabasename < file.sql
```

It will import file into selected database

Comment: Thanks, I know how to run it from the command line but I'm looking for a way how to tell IntelliJ IDEA how to do it. Maybe it wasn't clear from the title of my questions, I've updated it.